# Build gwas array database

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have experimental gwas microarray data results for more than 20K samples. Each sample has a numerical output value for approx 1.000.000 markers. So I have a theoretical table of 20000 x 1000000 values. The final goal is to create a web service in order to show the output values for a small number of samples. I have some dozens of variables to build the queries. My question is how to create this kind of database in an efficient way. It's MySQL the best option for this amount of data or it depends only on the server hardware?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**[MariaDB ColumnStore](https://mariadb.com/products/technology/columnstore)** is the way to go. The effect of **server hardware** on efficiency is only **11%** whereas that of **choice of DBMS** is **74%**.

Although MySQL(MariaDB row-based) is perfectly capable of handling the huge amount of data, ColumnStore DBMS will be suitable for your requirement.

A columnar database stores the data in columns instead of rows.
[image: Row vs Column RDBMS]

At a basic level, row stores are great for transaction processing. Column stores are great for highly analytical query models. Row stores have the ability to write data very quickly, whereas a column store is awesome at aggregating large volumes of data for a subset of columns.

One of the benefits of a columnar database is its crazy fast query speeds. In some cases, queries that took minutes or hours are completed in seconds. This makes columnar databases a good choice in a query-heavy environment. But you must make sure that the queries you run are really suited to a columnar database.

Links to refer:
[Why Should I Check Out a MySQL-Based Column Database?](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/mysql-based-column-database.html)

PS: [MariaDB AX](https://mariadb.com/products/solutions/olap-database-ax) is a good choice for analytics.